# How does lock(syncRoot) make sense on a static method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synclock

The following code is excerpted from the (Windows Identity Foundation SDK) template that MS uses to create a new Security Token Service Web Site.

```
public static CustomSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration Current  
{  
    get  
    {
        var key = CustomSecurityTokenServiceConfigurationKey;

        var httpAppState = HttpContext.Current.Application;

        var customConfiguration = httpAppState.Get(key)
            as CustomSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration;  

        if (customConfiguration == null)
        {  
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                customConfiguration = httpAppState.Get(key)
                    as CustomSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration;  

                if (customConfiguration == null)
                {
                    customConfiguration =
                        new CustomSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration();  
                    httpAppState.Add(key, customConfiguration);
                }
            }
        }    
        return customConfiguration;  
    }
}
```

I'm relatively new to multi-threaded programming.  I assume that the reason for the `lock` statement is to make this code thread-safe in the event that two web requests arrive at the web site at the same time.

However, I would have thought that using `lock (syncRoot)` would not make sense because `syncRoot` refers to the current instance that this method is operating on... but this is a static method!

How does this make sense?

Comment: @Paolo:  That's a good question.  Having said that, I assume its either a `static` variable or returned by a Singleton given its name.

Comment: @Bemrose: The assumption I've made is that `syncRoot` is a static class field that always holds the same instance: `private readonly object syncRoot = new object();`. Of course `syncRoot` could be defined as follows: `private object syncRoot { get { return new object(); } }`. In that case, we'd be in trouble :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C# `lock` statement does not lock on a method, but on the object it is supplied to. In your case `syncRoot`. Because there is only one instance of this `syncRoot` object, this ensures the `CustomSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration` class will only get created once for that app domain. So the property can be called in and executed in parallel. However, the block within the `lock { ... }` will never be called in parallel. However, it can be called multiple times and that is what the extra `if (customConfiguration == null)` statement is doing within the `lock` block. This mechanism is called a double checked lock.

Comment: OK.  Upon more carefully looking at this code, I see that `syncRoot` is declared as a static object.  I was just a bit confused because I'm used to seeing `syncRoot` appear as a member of the .net enumeration classes.

It looks like this block of code is the only place that the `syncRoot` is used, so it must have been declared for the express purpose of locking the block of code.

Comment: This is the common way to do locking using the `lock` keyword in .NET: Create a private readonly `Object` and use it as object to lock on.